# Delay between two threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a unit test method consisting of initializing and starting two threads:

```
    [Test]
    public void ReportGeneratorTwoThreadTest()
    {
        var logger = new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ReportGeneratorThreadTest));

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var estimatedReportSize = EstimatedReportSize.Normal;
            var reportGeneratorThread = new ReportGeneratorThread(logger, new ReportGenerator(20), estimatedReportSize);
            reportGeneratorThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        }
    }
```

I want to start the second thread 2 seconds after the first one by using a delay functionality. I have used both

```
Task.Delay(2000)
```

and

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

methods but none of them works. The second thread is still generated upon first one without any delay.

Comment: How are you measuring when the threads got started?

Comment: I'm debugging only those two threads among all threads in my project

Comment: And? How are you measuring when the threads got started? Task.Delay won't work without waiting for that task to complete but Thread.Sleep should work and delay your code. How did you verify that it didn't?

Comment: Please define "none of them works"

Comment: put sleep(10 minutes). then you will see the delay, your debugging is eating the 2 seconds

Comment: Sorry, I tested it once again and the expected delay is actually there. I think it was a debugging issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate your issue. This is the code I ran:

```
public static void Main()
{
     for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     {
         var t = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now));
         t.Start();
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

And it prints:

```
9/17/2015 1:18:49 PM 
9/17/2015 1:18:51 PM
```

Comment: The way he does it is already certain to work. This is not the problem. In general it's not a good idea to base answers on guesses. First, find the root cause.

Comment: @usr: Kindly undo your down-vote if you think my updated answer is not actively unhelpful.

Comment: Downvotes are not for "actively unhelpful" they are for "This answer is not useful", answers based on guesses are not considered useful by many users of this site.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, but the new answer is not a guess either. If someone still think that the answer deserves a down-vote, they should at least explain.

Comment: Your answer should have been a comment and a vote to close with off topic -> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced..." or Off topic -> "Answers seeking Debugging help..."

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I'm not sure enough that the problem in the question itself is not reproducible. I only am suggesting another example that runs fine. Anyways, the request to undo the down-vote is just a request. At the down-voters discretion. Moreover I don't know if it is him only who down-voted me.

Comment: @displayName sure, now the answer is correct. Once you earn the privilege to vote you should vote to close such questions. Welcome to stack overflow! I like your answers. Also, we chose our user name by the same principle as it seems :)

Comment: @usr: So it's you who suddenly up-voted so many answers of mine (and I am thankful). I was wrongly guessing that person to be another guy whom I answered recently. And yes.. nice display name you have. :D

Comment: @displayName the software did not allow me to pick "user" so it picked "usr". It was meant to be a throwaway account but "the system" pulled me in :)

Comment: @usr: Stack overflow is 'The Matrix' of Computer Scientists.